# How to cache method results in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lazy-initialization

In Python I can easily decorate methods so that they remember their result:

```
def store(self):
    a = line1()
    b = line2(a)
    return line3(b)
```

=>

```
from lazy import lazy

@lazy
def store(self):
    a = line1()
    b = line2(a)
    return line3(b)
```

Is there some similar idiom in Ruby for calculating method result only once?

Comment: Is the module for memoization in python really called `lazy`? That would be just wrong...

Comment: @ndn, not really. "Lazy evaluation is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed and which also avoids repeated evaluations" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: After so many years, this is the first time I hear *"avoids repeated evaluations"* as part of the definition. A person learns something new every day. Still I think it is a little misleading. Why not use the unambiguous *memoize*?

Comment: @ndn, it's a fair point. suspect it is due in part to the fact that it computes a single value (well, per instance), rather than accepting arguments. Plus being a more common English word.

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby this is generally called [memoization](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) and it takes the naive form of:

```
def store
  @store ||= begin
    a = line1
    b = line2(a)
    line3(b)
  end
end
```

There are important concerns if this code is used in a multi-threaded environment, though, which is why there are gems that manage this and ensure your lazy initializers are run only once if that's a concern.

Comment: Even disregarding threading, the naive form doesn't work for `nil` or `false` values. Thanks for the terminology tips though. I've found https://github.com/dkubb/memoizable

Comment: That's a good point, but 99% of the time the naive form will get the job done. That 1% of the time can be difficult to accommodate, like if `false` is a valid return value, so you do need to be aware of how this plays out. A proper memoization module covers you in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that works with `false` and `nil` too:

```
def store
  unless defined?(@store) 
    a = line1
    b = line2(a)
    @store = line3(b)
  end

  @store
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really. There is an operator (`||=`) that assigns a value only if the left operand is falsy (`nil` or `false`). Usually using that along with an instance variable does the trick.

[Memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) and [Memoizable](https://github.com/dkubb/memoizable) are gems often used for that purpose.

---

But my guess is that your question is more general - how do you implement method decorators in ruby?

```
class Module
  def decorate(method_name, &decoration)
    undecorated_method = instance_method(method_name)

    define_method(method_name) do
      decoration.call(&undecorated_method.bind(self))
    end
  end

  def memoize(method_name)
    @values ||= {}

    decorate(method_name) do |&evaluator|
      unless @values.key?(method_name)
        @values[method_name] = evaluator.call
      end

      @values[method_name]
    end
  end
end

class SuperComputer
  memoize def answer
    puts "Pending... 7½ million years remaining."
    42
  end
end

deep_mind = SuperComputer.new
deep_mind.answer # => 42 (and prints)
deep_mind.answer # => 42 (doesn't print)
```

---

Now there is a lot to be desired from this implementation (args, kwargs, blocks, per instance memoization, etc), but it should give you a general idea of how decorators can be implemented without the need for changes to the language itself.

Comment: change `@values[method_name] ||= evaluator.call` to `@values.has_key?(method_name) ? @values[method_name] : @values[method_name] = evaluator.call` and that will work for all falseys i.e `nil` and `false`

Comment: @bjhaid, initially I wanted to keep it as basic as possible. Done.

Comment: This answer is very interesting